# issue with render json for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I have this array coming from my server. Which is returned like this when i use puts:

```
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;66.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;128.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;246.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;243.20
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.86
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.50
```

so i just tried to do this:

```
price1.each do |price11|
  price11.json {render json: price11.as_json}
end
```

However this returns this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `json' for ["formatted_total_price", "&Acirc;&pound;66.00"]:Array):
```

What I'm wanting is to have the `formatted_total_price` and the `&Acirc;&pound;66.00` to match up to look like this:

```
"formatted_total_price":"&Acirc;&pound;66.00"
```

Heres the actual code i have:

```
doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
       if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
         price1 = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_total_price)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         description = text.to_s.scan(/\"(ticket_desc)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         price = price1 + description
         price1.each do |price11|
           price11.json {render json: price11.as_json}
         end
       end
```

**Edit**
Ok so heres what i have:

```
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;66.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;128.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;246.00
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;243.20
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.86
formatted_total_price
&Acirc;&pound;242.50
ticket_desc
Later Owl Ticket
ticket_desc
Later Owl Ticket+Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket
ticket_desc
Later Owl + Chance For VIP Upgrade
ticket_desc
VIP Ticket
ticket_desc
VIP Ticket + Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket
ticket_desc
Skydeck Package
ticket_desc
5 Person Skydeck Table
ticket_desc
7 Person Skydeck Table
ticket_desc
10 Person Skydeck Table
```

What i want is kinda the same as last time but more like this:

```
"formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;66.00",
"ticket_desc" : "Later Owl Ticket"
```

Also if ticket_desc has anything that include a `+` symbol i want it ignored (i can do this myself unless you know of a better way!!)

Comment: price11 is a string if I understand the code correctly? So why should a string have a .json method ? Also , why do you try to render json inside the each loop , you should render only once per the request I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = Array.new

price1.each do |p|
    a.merge({p[0] => p[1]})
end

render json: a.to_json
```

or simply you can do

```
price1.map{|a| { a[0] => a[1] } }.to_json
```

Comment: Hey there! This is perfect, Quick extra question. If i wanted to add the description. But have it so the `description: description` was in the same  first array? (so description1 would be wiht the first formatted total price) how would i do this?

Comment: can you give the sample input and the exact output you want to have ?

Comment: I'll add it in now